# How to execute specific threadpool/sampler on specific slave node in distributed Jmeter setup

Tags: performance, jmeter

we are using Jmeter with distributed nodes (one master and 4 clients). Currently we are using Jmeter version 5.4
I believe there is no good way to distribute the specific part of the test plan to specific slave node, I mean assuming there are 4 thread pools doing some distinct tasks and I would like to distribute each thread pool onto each slave node (i.e. one thread pool tasks are get executed on each node). Is this possible to achieve with latest Jmeter version and if you could share your experts opinion then that would greatly helpful for our use case. I am not finding specific answer but one of the blazemeter blog shows it can be possible using IF controller https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

All JMeter slaves are executing the same .jmx test plan as it is, if you want to distribute certain samplers to be run on certain slaves:

1. Put them under [If Controllers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)
2. Use [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function as the If Controller's condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${__machineName()}"=="hostname of your slave 1",)}
   ```

   [image]